# Rename database pointer in SharePoint 2010

Tags: database, rename

I've run into a problem regarding the naming of the database server on our SharePoint 2010 installation.

I've used the FQDN, where it's best pratice to use the NETBIOS name of the SQL server apparently. So how do I tell SharePoint to use mysqlname instead of mysqlname.mycompany.local ?

Comment: If the problem is that the sharepoint installation is looking for a SQL server with FQDN, I dont see how a SQL server with the same name or alias should help?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of issues with using a FQDN for the SQL Server... setting up an alias would require the alias name be a FQDN... so I agree an alias won't likely solve the problem. A farm backup/restore redirected to a new database may work.

Answer (score 1):

check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx, there's a trick you can do on the server to set a server alias.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the powershell cmdlet called `Rename-SPServer`

For instance:

```
Rename-SPServer -Identity "mysqlname.mycompany.local" -Name "mysqlname"
```

You will probably have to reprovision the User Profile Sync etc after it though.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upvote an answer or comment on an answer, but I wanted to say that Dan The Man's response to use Rename-SPServer works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving off of a FQDN should be possible without reinstallation, but it will not be easy.

Content databases can be detached from and reattached to SharePoint with the correct server name. For service application databases it's a bit more difficult but perhaps Rename-SPServer can do the trick. You could use the configuration wizard to remove the server from the farm and then add it again but pointing to the NetBIOS name for the SQL server. Testing will be the key here I'm afraid.

In any case, a good practice is to create SQL aliases to have more flexibility in the future. You can refer to [Move database to new SQL Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51392/move-database-to-new-sql-server/51429#51429) for information.